# What is your favorite proof of the Pythagorean Theorem? Why?

Tags: geometry, alternative-proof

My favorite
is Euclid's original proof
for two reasons:

First, it requires
minimal raw material.
It only needs the result
that the area of a triangle
is half the area
of a rectangle
with the same base and altitude.

Second,
it gives additional information,
in that it shows
how to divide the
square on the hypotenuse
into two rectangles
each of which
is equal in area
to one of the
squares on the legs.

So, 
what's yours?

Comment: Take a triangle $ABC$ with right angle at $C$. Drop a perpendicular from $C$ to $P$ on $AB$, This divides the original triangle into two triangles similar to the original. The area of the original is  $\kappa c^2$ for some constant $\kappa$. By a scaling argument the two little triangles have area $\kappa a^2$ and $\kappa b^2$, and it is clear that $\kappa c^2=\kappa a^2+\kappa b^2$.

Answer (score 2):

> Let $ABC$ be a right triangle, with right angle at $A$. Let $H$ be the foot of the altitude from $A$. Triangles $ABH$, $ACH$ and $ABC$ are similar, being their areas proportional to the square of the hypothenuses, that is,
>   $$a^2=b^2+c^2$$

For brevity.

Comment: Somehow this is much more satisfying than any other proof.  I am not quite sure why, but I think most mathematicians would agree that it is vastly superior to the hundreds of other proofs via chopping and rearranging.

Answer (score 0):

I would say [Garfield's proof](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt668/emt668.student.folders/headangela/essay1/pythagorean.html), which shows and two different ways to represent the area of the trapezoid. In that site it is the last one. Plus, the guy was one of our presidents at one point!